# Probability of code line executed in kth iteration

Tags: algorithm, probability, pseudocode

```
RANDOM MIN(A[1::n])

min = infinity

for i = 1 to n in random order

        if A[i] < min
            min = A[i] ---- (*)
return min
```

What is the probability that line * gets executed for kth iteration?

I found it to be 1/n, except for the first iteration.

The reason is that the random order generates n! possible outcomes and in kth iteration A[kth generated outcome] could be any of the n no. and for it to be minimum there are n possibilities, hence 1/n.

An example: for n = 3, k=2
input : (10, 11, 12) or any combination of 3 nos

```
permutations    if A[2] < min
  123              N
  132              N
  213              Y
  231              N 
  312              Y//edited mislabeled it earlier
  321              Y
```

there the probability in 2nd iteration for the line execute is same as all the other 1/n except the first line which is 1 cause it always holds

Please let me know if I am wrong, because my professor says it's 1/k, and I am not satisfied with his explanation!

Comment: this question does not at all seem to be c related. Please re-tag as appropriate.

Comment: What language is it? Python?

Comment: sry that was my first post, will take care of it next time @IvayloStrandjev

Comment: its just an alogorithm, can I tag it as algorithm?

Comment: @rtmatchbox you can still edit your question and change the tags as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the question "where the minimum is" and "whether the line gets executed".

The minimum is in a uniformly random position, so with probability 1/N it's in one specific position.

But to find it, you need to execute the line, and this happens with diminishing probability:

1. A[1] is less than infinity with probabilty one
2. A[2] is less than A[1] with probability 1/2.

Etc.

Comment: what about my example I am not able to comprehend it, can you please explain it. .

Comment: @rtmatchbox: You mislabelled the `321` case.

Comment: Brilliant. . a mapping mistake, and everything boomed, thankyou soo much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Round 1: 1 in 1 chance it is the smallest so far
Round 2: 1 in 2 chance it is the smallest so far
Round 3: 1 in 3 chance it is the smallest so far
Round 4: 1 in 4 chance it is the smallest so far
...
...
Round k: 1 in K chance it is the smallest so far
```

Comment: That's a good start. Maybe you should elaborate on that and lead over to harmonic numbers...

Comment: I'm just a computer guy with some common and some math sense. :)  I thought I'd explain it simply.  I don't know about harmonic numbers.  One interesting thing is that I don't think "n" really matters.  It is a just a sequence of DIFFERENT numbers and you are looking at the odds that the next one is the smallest.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the question as "how often is line executed". So your answer is good as it is.

Comment: When I said Round 1 I meant the first time through the loop.  On the fourth time through the loop there have been four numbers.  One of those will be the smallest.  The fourth number has a 1 in 4 chance of being the smallest number so far.  So there would be a 1/4 chance of running the line with the *.  On the fifth time through the loop, there will have been five numbers, the fifth (last) number has a 1/5 chance of being the smallest.  Etc.  The Kth number would have a 1/k chance...